# Bare-Metal K8s: How to preserve source IP of client and direct traffic to nginx replica on current server on

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service

I would like to ask you about some assistance:

Entrypoint to cluster for http/https is NGINX: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.25.0 running as deamonset

I want to achieve 2 things:

1. preserve source IP of client
2. direct traffic to nginx replica on
       current server (so if request is sent to server A, listed as
       externalIP address, nginx on node A should handle it)

Questions:

- How is it possible?
- Is it possible without nodeport? *Control plane can be started with custom --service-node-port-range so I can add nodeport for 80
  and 443, but it looks a little bit like a hack (after reading about
  nodeport intended usage)*

I was considering using **metallb**, but layer2 configuration will cause bottleneck (high traffic on cluster). I am not sure if BGP will solve this problem.

- Kubernetes **v15**
- Bare-metal
- Ubuntu **18.04**
- Docker **(18.9)** and WeaveNet **(2.6)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can preserve the source IP of client by using `externalTrafficPolicy` set to `local`, this will proxy requests to local endpoints. This is explained on [Source IP for Services with Type=NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-type-nodeport).

Can should also have a look at [Using Source IP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/).

In case of [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/):

> MetalLB respects the service’s  `externalTrafficPolicy`  option, and implements two different announcement modes depending on what policy you select. If you’re familiar with Google Cloud’s Kubernetes load balancers, you can probably skip this section: MetalLB’s behaviors and tradeoffs are identical.
>
> #### [“Local” traffic policy](https://v0-2-0--metallb.netlify.com/usage/#local-traffic-policy)
>
> With the  `Local`  traffic policy, nodes will only attract traffic if they are running one or more of the service’s pods locally. The BGP routers will load-balance incoming traffic only across those nodes that are currently hosting the service. On each node, the traffic is forwarded only to local pods by  `kube-proxy`, there is no “horizontal” traffic flow between nodes.
>
> This policy provides the most efficient flow of traffic to your service. Furthermore, because  `kube-proxy`  doesn’t need to send traffic between cluster nodes, your pods can see the real source IP address of incoming connections.
>
> The downside of this policy is that it treats each cluster node as one “unit” of load-balancing, regardless of how many of the service’s pods are running on that node. This may result in traffic imbalances to your pods.
>
> For example, if your service has 2 pods running on node A and one pod running on node B, the  `Local`  traffic policy will send 50% of the service’s traffic to each  *node*. Node A will split the traffic it receives evenly between its two pods, so the final per-pod load distribution is 25% for each of node A’s pods, and 50% for node B’s pod. In contrast, if you used the  `Cluster`  traffic policy, each pod would receive 33% of the overall traffic.
>
> In general, when using the  `Local`  traffic policy, it’s recommended to finely control the mapping of your pods to nodes, for example using [node anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity), so that an even traffic split across nodes translates to an even traffic split across pods.

You need to take for the account the limitations of [BGP routing protocol](https://v0-2-0--metallb.netlify.com/usage/#limitations) for MetalLB.

Please also have a look at this blog post [Using MetalLb with Kind](https://mauilion.dev/posts/kind-metallb/).